# how to clear the drawn rectangles in picturebox using graphics?

Tags: c#, winforms

I drawn 12 rectangles in picturebox with some co-ordinates, now i want to clear the drawn rectangles in picturebox before loading the next image in the same picturebox. 
For Drawing rectangles i used following code,

```
>  g.DrawRectangle(pen1, rect);
```

where g is Graphics, pen1= new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red, 2F); and rect is Rectangle with x,y,width and height co-ordinates.

And also i want my drawn graphics to resize for that i used PosSizableRect Enum with picturebox Mousedown, mousemove and Mouseleave event , and my rectangle  cursor is changed, so that user can resize the drawn rectangle co-ordinates.

How can i clear the drawn rectangles in PictureBox before loading the Next Image in the same PictureBox?
I tried the following solution ,but nothing works for me.
g.Clear(Color.Red);  , this.Invalidate(); ,  pictureBox1.Refresh(); pictureBox1.Image=null; and img.Dispose();

Pls guide me !!! how can i proceed further?

Comment: It depends how you draw the rectangles. If you use *g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();* then a simple *this.Invalidate();* works just fine. If you have an image to your pictureBox1 eg *pictureBox1.Image = img* and you draw on *img* then you have to clear your *img* and invalidate. Show some code

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to remove the rectangles that have been drawn to restore the image to the original state, or are you intending to draw a "clear" (i.e. white) rectangle onto the picture ?

In the second case, you should use Graphics.FillRectangle.

In the first case, you need to keep a copy of the original image and repaint it when you want to eliminate the rectangles you have drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your picturebox blank (erasing fully) by the following code:

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved unless you actually store the image data used. Unless you want to just fill the picturebox with ex. white. I wrote a simple class for you to achieve this.

```
public class RestorablePictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        private Image _restoreImage;
        private Image _restoreBackgroundImage;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            if (_restoreImage != null) _restoreImage.Dispose();
            if (_restoreBackgroundImage != null) _restoreBackgroundImage.Dispose();

            _restoreImage = this.Image;
            _restoreBackgroundImage = this.BackgroundImage;

            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }

        public void Restore(bool fill = false)
        {
            if (fill)
            {
                if (_restoreImage != null) _restoreImage.Dispose();
                if (_restoreBackgroundImage != null) _restoreBackgroundImage.Dispose();

                using (var gfx = this.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height); // Change Brushes.White to the color you want or use new SolidBrush(Color)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_restoreImage != null) this.Image = _restoreImage;
                if (_restoreBackgroundImage != null) this.BackgroundImage = _restoreBackgroundImage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i use this class in my code, actually i'm having a clear button in my code, when i click that button rectangle should clear from my picturebox , I copied this class in my Code. I'm beginner in C#.net , so pls guide me, how to use this class methods in my code to clear a rectangle from picturebox ??

Comment: Change your PictureBox to this PictureBox. You can drag it from your toolbox (after building once) or create it like "var restorePic = new RestorablePictureBox();"